# Why does chaining match expressions does not compile?

Tags: scala

Chaining match expressions does not compile.

```
val x = Array("abc", "pqr")

x match {
  case Array("abc", _*) => Some("abc is first")
  case Array("xyz", _*) => Some("xyz is first")
  case _ => None
} match {
  case Some(x) => x
  case _ => "Either empty or incorrect first entry"
}
```

While the following compiles fine:

```
(x match {
  case Array("abc", _*) => Some("abc is first")
  case Array("xyz", _*) => Some("xyz is first")
  case _ => None
}) match {
  case Some(x) => x
  case _ => "Either empty or incorrect first entry"
}
```

Why does the later version (where first match expression is in paranthesis) compile fine while earlier one does not?

Comment: There is nothing to say here except `match` is not a method, but keyword and compiler works this way.

Answer (score 4):

If it were allowed, you couldn't do:

```
scala> List(1,2,3) last match { case 3 => true }
warning: there were 1 feature warning(s); re-run with -feature for details
res6: Boolean = true
```

That is, if it were infix notation, then the thing to the left could not be postfix.

Disallowing infix match permits a postfix scrutinee.

That expression is parsed the natural way

```
(List(1,2,3) last) match { case 3 => true }
```

that is, if postfix notation is natural and not unholy.

The feature warning is for `import language.postfixOps`.  Perhaps with that feature turned off, the Defenders of the Good would be willing to entertain `import language.infixMatch`.

Consider constructs that are syntactic siblings to `match`, that are not infixable without parens:

```
scala> if (true) 1 else 2 match { case 1 => false }
res4: AnyVal = 1   // not false

scala> (if (true) 1 else 2) match { case 1 => false }
res1: Boolean = false
```

or

```
scala> throw new IllegalStateException match { case e => "ok" }
<console>:11: error: type mismatch;   // not "ok", or rather, Nothing
 found   : String("ok")
 required: Throwable
              throw new IllegalStateException match { case e => "ok" }
                                                                ^

scala> (throw new IllegalStateException) match { case e => "ok" }
java.lang.IllegalStateException
```